# "The filename or extension is too long" while installing confluent-kafka?

Tags: python, windows, apache-kafka, pip

I have some trouble installing confluent-kafka by using "pip install confluent-kafka". But I got this error: "The filename or extension is too long." Details are below.

```
Collecting confluent-kafka
  Using cached confluent-kafka-1.8.2.tar.gz (104 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: confluent-kafka
  Building wheel for confluent-kafka (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [48 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka
      copying src\confluent_kafka\deserializing_consumer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka
      copying src\confluent_kafka\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka
      copying src\confluent_kafka\serializing_producer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka
      copying src\confluent_kafka\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\admin
      copying src\confluent_kafka\admin\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\admin
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\cached_schema_registry_client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\load.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\kafkatest
      copying src\confluent_kafka\kafkatest\verifiable_client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\kafkatest
      copying src\confluent_kafka\kafkatest\verifiable_consumer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\kafkatest
      copying src\confluent_kafka\kafkatest\verifiable_producer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\kafkatest
      copying src\confluent_kafka\kafkatest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\kafkatest
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\avro.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\json_schema.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\protobuf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\schema_registry_client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\serialization
      copying src\confluent_kafka\serialization\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\serialization
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro\serializer
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\serializer\message_serializer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro\serializer
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\serializer\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro\serializer
      running build_ext
      building 'confluent_kafka.cimpl' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e4mpsn3s
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e4mpsn3s\confluent-kafka_a53471ea97464e83aa35d4164a2c7040
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e4mpsn3s\confluent-kafka_a53471ea97464e83aa35d4164a2c7040\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e4mpsn3s\confluent-kafka_a53471ea97464e83aa35d4164a2c7040\src\confluent_kafka
      error: could not create 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e4mpsn3s\confluent-kafka_a53471ea97464e83aa35d4164a2c7040\src\confluent_kafka': The filename or extension is too long
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for confluent-kafka
  Running setup.py clean for confluent-kafka
Failed to build confluent-kafka
Installing collected packages: confluent-kafka
  Running setup.py install for confluent-kafka ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for confluent-kafka did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [50 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka
      copying src\confluent_kafka\deserializing_consumer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka
      copying src\confluent_kafka\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka
      copying src\confluent_kafka\serializing_producer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka
      copying src\confluent_kafka\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\admin
      copying src\confluent_kafka\admin\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\admin
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\cached_schema_registry_client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\load.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\kafkatest
      copying src\confluent_kafka\kafkatest\verifiable_client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\kafkatest
      copying src\confluent_kafka\kafkatest\verifiable_consumer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\kafkatest
      copying src\confluent_kafka\kafkatest\verifiable_producer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\kafkatest
      copying src\confluent_kafka\kafkatest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\kafkatest
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\avro.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\json_schema.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\protobuf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\schema_registry_client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      copying src\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\schema_registry
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\serialization
      copying src\confluent_kafka\serialization\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\serialization
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro\serializer
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\serializer\message_serializer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro\serializer
      copying src\confluent_kafka\avro\serializer\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\confluent_kafka\avro\serializer
      running build_ext
      building 'confluent_kafka.cimpl' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e4mpsn3s
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e4mpsn3s\confluent-kafka_a53471ea97464e83aa35d4164a2c7040
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e4mpsn3s\confluent-kafka_a53471ea97464e83aa35d4164a2c7040\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e4mpsn3s\confluent-kafka_a53471ea97464e83aa35d4164a2c7040\src\confluent_kafka
      error: could not create 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e4mpsn3s\confluent-kafka_a53471ea97464e83aa35d4164a2c7040\src\confluent_kafka': The filename or extension is too long
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> confluent-kafka

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried to use other method in this link "https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1002". But it also doesn't work.

Please help me!!

Comment: I think you should try renaming something in this path... `build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Temp`? Try to `set TEMP` to something shorter before running pip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows versions lower than 1607 have limitations in place for maximum length for a path (set by MAX_PATH), which restricts file paths' lengths to be capped at 260 characters.

Fortunately, if you are running Windows 10 version 1607, you can enable support for long paths:

1. Click `Win`+`R`
2. Type `regedit` and press `Enter`
3. Go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`
4. Edit or create a key named `LongPathsEnabled` (type: `REG_DWORD`)
5. Enter `1` as its value and press `OK`.
6. Restart your system and try again. It should work now.

**Read more:** [Maximum Path Length Limitation in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell)