# How to solve "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing `something`: The filename or extension is too long." while pip installing in a long path

Tags: python, windows, pip

When I am trying to pip install some packages for a python project in a directory with a long path name an error pops up. It has more to do with Windows than Python as it is a DLL file load error.

```
  File "C:\wgyikhefghwefuyhedg\ausyfgyhfhbsdguifhlygsfkugysfsdfukysdgfksd\jsgkasdfhkghksduyfgsajkfgusadufgfkyhsudgfkusdyfbsfgsudkfgsduyfgasdku\qwertyuiop\sierghdsyfgh\iaseufbhsaldgj\qasderf\.venv\lib\site-packages\charset_normalizer\cd.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .md import is_suspiciously_successive_range
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing md__mypyc: The filename or extension is too long.
```

The path given here is abstract, but it is important that the path is very long.

I did try [this](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#removing-the-max-path-limitation) and still the issue persists. Yes, I did restart my machine.

The import works fine when running pip install on a shorter path.

Trying to install some packages for a python project in a directory with long path.

Expected to install fine without errors. Throwing path too long error instead.

Comment: You will need to change where that's installed, as this is a Windows problem as you have identified.

Comment: @metatoaster there is no workaround? It needs to be inside a path that is long. Having it in a shorter path is not an option.

Comment: As noted, this is a Windows issue.  If you are running Windows 10 version 1607 or later try [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477633/the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-while-installing-confluent-kafka/71672151#71672151).

Comment: @metatoaster Tried that, did not work.

Comment: You may also need to reboot.  Do ensure your operating system is of the version as specified or later. As this is an OS issue and/or Python interpreter issue, you may try to file an issue on the [CPython issue tracker](https://github.com/python/cpython/) and hope they might have a workaround implemented for this issue some time in the future for Windows users.